# Writing a simple JUnit test for an intro to software QA class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, netbeans, junit

I am tasked with writing a small program along with a JUnit and Coverage test and I am having some issues with understanding how a JUnit will be written.

I have written JUnit tests before, with some help from more knowledgeable teammates, for other class projects. They have all been for classes that we could instantiate, use, and then inspect (with `assert...()`).

The program we were told to write is a simple console application that takes in some values, computes something, and returns. Below is what I have written, it simply takes in a variable number of numbers between some range and computes the min, max, and average of the values.

The issue I am having is that I am not sure how I can write a JUnit for this in terms of how I have written them before. I am not sure how I can "falsify" user input to the console in the unit test.

I am asking for help in how I might go about writing a JUnit test for this piece of software.

```
package softqa_assignment2;

import java.io.Console;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class SoftQA_Assignment2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Console cons = System.console();
        if (cons == null) 
        {
            System.err.println("System could not provide console, exiting");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("--------------------");
        System.out.println("Welcome, this program computes the minimum, maximum, and average of 10-20 numbers.");
        System.out.println("Input \"Q\" at anytime to quit.");
        System.out.println("--------------------");

        int numVals = 0;
        boolean gotNumVals = false;
        while(!gotNumVals)
        {
            String numValsStr = cons.readLine("Enter number of numbers (10-20): ");
            if(numValsStr.equals("Q"))
            {
                System.err.println("Encountered \"Q\", quiting program...");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            try
            {
                numVals = Integer.parseInt(numValsStr);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Please input a integer value between 10 and 20.");
                continue;
            }

            if(numVals < 10 || numVals > 20)
            {
                System.out.println("Please input a integer value between 10 and 20.");
                continue;
            }
            else
                gotNumVals = true;
        }

        System.out.println("--------------------");
        int valsGot = 0;
        LinkedList<Double> vals = new LinkedList<>();
        while(valsGot < numVals)
        {
            String numValueStr = cons.readLine((valsGot + 1) + ": Enter a number: ");
            if(numValueStr.equals("Q"))
            {
                System.err.println("Encountered \"Q\", quiting program...");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            double numToAdd = 0;
            try
            {
                numToAdd = Double.parseDouble(numValueStr);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Please input a proper value.");
                continue;
            }

            vals.add(numToAdd);
            valsGot++;
        }

        System.out.println("--------------------");
        System.out.println("Done getting numbers, computing output...");
        System.out.println("--------------------");

        double min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        double avg = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++)
        {
            avg += vals.get(i);
            if(vals.get(i) < min)
                min = vals.get(i);
            if(vals.get(i) > max)
                max = vals.get(i);
        }
        avg /= vals.size();

        System.out.println("Minimum: " + min + "\n Maximum: " + max + "\n Average: " + avg);
        System.out.println("--------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, break your code down into small units, i.e. methods. All you can currently do is to invoke `main()` from JUnit, and test the entire program in one go. It's easier to test a little bit of the program that does just one thing that trying to test the whole program in one go.

Comment: Your unit tests should not be concerned with user input via a console. They should test the computational part of the code. If you refactor this code into a separate class/method, then it should become clearer how to unit test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first step is to [refactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) your code into small, reusable, purposeful methods.  For example, examine this block of code near the end of your `main` method:

```
double min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
double avg = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++)
{
    avg += vals.get(i);
    if(vals.get(i) < min)
        min = vals.get(i);
    if(vals.get(i) > max)
        max = vals.get(i);
}
avg /= vals.size();
```

It could be refactored to:

```
Stats stats = getStatsFromVals(vals);
```

With the new method defined as:

```
static Stats getStatsFromVals(List<Double> vals) {
  double min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
  double avg = 0.0;
  for(double val : vals) {
    avg += val;
    if(val < min)
      min = val;
    if(val > max)
      max = val;
  }
  avg /= vals.size();
  return new Stats(min, max, avg);
}
```

Where `Stats` would be a [static nested class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) you define to serve as a value class that holds all the stats values you are calculating.

Now you have a method which is both logically and physically a unit, making it a prime candidate for unit testing.

```
@Test
public static void testGetStats() {
  List<Double> testList = Arrays.asList("1.0, 2.0, 3.0");
  Stats stats = MainClass.getStatsFromVals(testList);
  assertEquals(1.0, stats.min);
  assertEquals(3.0, stats.max);      
  assertEquals(2.0, Math.rint(stats.avg)); // risky FP math
}
```

As was mentioned in the comments, the key is to making each method take its parameter as an input, so that you can separate the console input from the application logic.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a boolean variable, lets say condition = false.

Now if the program is able to run properly without any errors, then after you have computed your min/max/average, you can set it to true. And then assert with this. This assert can be made in finally block after try and catch block. In case of any error, catch will be called and condition should not be set to true. Hence assert should return negation.

If you already know the values that user will enter, then rather assert with the proper min/average values.